# Duplicated vertex groups in separate object don't deform like the originals

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I made a character in MakeHuman and imported it into blender using the MHX2 import script. Quite impressive!

I am trying to model a pair of trousers, but for some reason I can't get them to move (properly) with the character's legs.

In this example, I have simply selected the vertices I will be using to eventually make the pants, duplicated them, and separated them to a new object. Nothing else.

Here is a picture of the character before changing his pose:
[image]

This is what happens *after* I move his thigh bone:
[image]

As you can see, most of the mesh moves correctly except for the seam (the vertices around the top, ones that are no longer connected to anything above).

I thought it might be a problem with the weights but they seem to have copied over flawlessly.

[image]

Any ideas?

[image]